# Windows 7 Issue with links

Tags: windows-7

I'm having an issue with links displaying on my intranet pages. The links occur in any instance where the word Microsoft appears. There is no code around the word in my source code - they just appear and link to Microsoft's site. I work in Windows 7. How do I prevent these links from occurring?

Comment: you need to be *a lot* more descriptive of the problem.  are they happening only for you?  in just one browser or all?

Answer (score 2):

That almost sounds like something is inserting a link after the page loads. I would take a look at where the links send you. If it is somewhere that is not part of your intranet, you probably have some malware on your system.

I would try downloading a different browser like Google Chrome and viewing the page again. The nice thing about chrome is that you can "Inspect elements" by right clicking on them. If the links still show up in chrome, there could be some javascript on the page that is causing it.

If you think it is a script on the page, install Firefox and use the [NoScript](http://noscript.net/) plugin (or something similar) to stop all scripting on the page and see if that changes the behavior.

Comment: This is the probably answer: there is a foistware/malware/adware toolbar or other handler being loaded on the local machine. Check ad/remove programs, also check the loaded/active browser plugins for each browser that exhibits this behavior. I have seen this on several coworker's machines, but I don't recall the name of the specific software at the moment. If it is not, then check the source code *on the webserver*. Hosting may have been compromised.